# Ensure a string matches a certain format in c

Tags: c, string

How can compare a string for matching a special format in c?

I want to check whether a string match to  "PCn.Value".

ie. It must match PC1.value, PC2.value,...

Comment: [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Comment: You should write a piece of code showing how exactly you want to validate, and mark it with comment "validate here" or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of checking if a string matches a given format is a rather broad and tricky topic.  As a general solution, [regexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are a useful tool, as are [parsing expression grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar).  However, in your case, it's rather simple, especially if `n` only goes up to 9.  Here's a very computationally efficient solution in that case:

```
#include <string.h>
char check_PC_N_dot_value(char* str) {
    // only works when 0 <= n <= 9
    return
        str[0] == 'P' &&
        str[1] == 'C' &&
        str[2] >= '0' &&
        str[2] <= '9' &&
        str[3] == '.' &&
        str[4] == 'v' &&
        str[5] == 'a' &&
        str[6] == 'l' &&
        str[7] == 'u' &&
        str[8] == 'e' &&
        str[9] == 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't check the string isn't longer than expected.

Answer (score 5):

`sscanf()` could help

```
char S[32];
if (sscanf(str, "PC%[0-9].Valu%1[e]%c", S, &S[30], &S[30])==2)
```

Comment: thanks this works
sscanf(str, "PC%d.Value", &x) is 1 on matching

Comment: That doesn't check if any part of ".Value" matches.

Comment: And, it permits values like "PC-1.Value".

Comment: @ams you are right,  it permits values like "PC 1 .Value" (with spaces)

Comment: You might want the format to be `"%u"` instead, to only allow unsigned values. Although it will allow it to match e.g. `"PC+1.Value"` too.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg and for the spaces ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg using %u will not solve the problem. answer updated

Comment: @MOHAMED why 32 byte char array s ?

Comment: @Shihab the number will be saved in the char array S as string format

Comment: It still doesn't actually check that the ".Value" exists.

Comment: @ams indeed this does not actually check that the ".Value" exists

Comment: @ams answer updated. the new format check that  ".Value" exists

Comment: @ams the new string format will check even that there is no extra chracters after the ".Value".  So the "PC30.Valueqq" will be ignored

Comment: @MOHAMED: That's why my answer compares `%n` against `strlen(s)`.

Comment: The latest edit introduces a bug when the number is 30 characters long, and gives no advantage. The arbitrary 32 character limit was already a security vulnerability, but this is just pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a single digit number, this is probably both sufficient and the most efficient:

```
if (strncmp (s, "PC", 2)
    && (s[2] >= '0' && s[2] <= '9')
    && strcmp (s+3, ".value"))
  {
    do_stuff_if_string_matches(s[2]-'0');
  }
```

Alternatively, if you need arbitrary unsigned integers:

```
char n[SOME_SIZE];
int count = 0;
if (sscanf (s, "PC%[0-9].value%n", n, &count)
    && count == strlen (s))
  {
    /* `n' now contains the number as a string.  */
    do_stuff_if_string_matches(atoi(n));
  }
```

Comment: I used "%[0-9]" instead and it's a string capture

Answer (score 0):

Use [posix regex](http://www.peope.net/old/regex.html) so you will be ready for further, more complex tests.

e.g.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

...
...
regex_t regex;
int reti;

if (regcomp(&regex, "PC[[:digit:]]+\.value", 0))
{
    printf("Error compiling regex\n");
    return(1);
}

reti = regexec(&regex, yourstring, 0, NULL, 0);

if (reti == 0)
    printf("String matches\n");
else
{
    if (reti == REG_NOMATCH)
        printf("String not matches\n");
    else
        printf("Error\n");
}

regfree(&regex);
```