# Reading multiple values from formatted string using sscanf

Tags: c, regex, scanf

I'm trying to extract two values from a string. The first is an 8 digit hexadecimal value, and the second is an unsigned 1-4 digit value. The values should also be preceded by a command which tells the program what to do with the values, in this case "read". Some examples of the format:

```
"read 0x1234ABCD 2000"
"read 0x00000001 10"
```

I want to both extract the two values and confirm the format, and have the following lines of code:

```
uint addr;
uint len;

int n = sscanf(str, "read 0x%x[0-9a-fA-F]{8} %u[0-9]{1,4}", &addr, &len);

if (n != 2){
    // Wrong format...
}
```

The hex-value is read correctly, but the second value is not and n is always 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `scanf` does *not* do regular expressions. To read up to eight hexadecimal digits just use `"%8x"`. See e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Hmm, I was going of this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013031/ensure-a-string-matches-a-certain-format-in-c). Is that not regex?

Comment: Assuming you mean e.g. `"%[0-9]"`, then no it's not a regex, but it is a variant that uses *simple* character classes.

Comment: Ok, I tried the following in sscanf "read 0x%8x %u", and it worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: If you [read about the `scanf()` family](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2) you will see that they do not use regular expressions. The only regular expressions I see in the linked question involve the POSIX `regex.h`.

Comment: sscanf read string by string. you have to use for loop to read both the strings. ** int n = sscanf(str, "read 0x%8x %d", &addr, &len); ** itself enough to read. no need of regex.

Comment: Note that `scanf()`-style parsing is really hard to make robust and reliable. I've seen all kinds of crazy bugs caused by malformed data - even changing the spacing of data can mess things up.  And you *will* get malformed data, nevermind data that perfectly fits whatever specification you coded to but is in some combination or pattern that you didn't think of.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Agree `scanf()` can be a challenge, yet the greater challenge, IMO, is that the syntax requirements are incomplete from the beginning: only providing _some_ acceptable forms and _some_ unacceptable forms.  Any solution is prone to maintenance trouble when the original goal was allowed to be imprecise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

```
Input:  "read 0x1234ABCD 2000"
Format: "read 0x%x[0-9a-fA-F]{8} %u[0-9]{1,4}"
```

Input `"read 0x"` matches the format `"read 0x"`.  Good so far.

Input `"1234ABCD"` matches the format `"%x"`.  Good so far.  +1 to the return value.

Input `" "` does not match the format `"["`.  Scanning stops.  `sscanf()` returns 1.

---

Alternatives, read the 2nd value as a decimal value.

```
const char *f1 = "read 0x%x %u";
const char *f2 = "read 0x%x%u";   // Space not need, yet looks good
const char *f3 = "read %x%u";     // Always read addr as hex, even with/without 0x
const char *f4 = "read %x %u";
const char *f5 = "read%x%u";

unsigned addr;
unsigned len;
int n = sscanf(str, fn, &addr, &len);  // select format from above
```

The above code does not fail

```
"read 0x0x123 +1234"
"read 0x123 456 xyz"
"read 0x123 12345"
"read 0x+123 -123"
```

---

Should OP want more error checking.  The 8 limits the text input for `addr` to 8 non-white-space characters.   `sentinel` detects tailing non-white-space garbage.

```
unsigned addr;
unsigned len;
char sentinel;
int n = sscanf(str, "read 0x%8x %4u %c", &addr, &len, &sentinel);
if (n != 2){
  // Wrong format...
}
```

The above does fail

```
"read 0x123 456 xyz"
```

---

What is closest to OP original code  obliges more work.  Use `"%[...]"` to test for an allowable *scan set*.

```
#define F_RD    "read"
#define F_SP    "%*[ ]"
#define F_ADDR  "0x%8[0-9a-fA-F]"
#define F_LEN   "%4[0-9]"
#define F_SEN   " %c"
char addr_s[8+1];
char len_s[4+1];
char sentinel;
int n = sscanf(str, F_RD F_SP F_ADDR F_SP F_LEN F_SEN, addr_s, len_s, &sentinel);
if (n == 2){
  // Success
  unsigned long addr = strtoul(addr_s, (char **)NULL, 16);
  unsigned len = strtoul(len_s, (char **)NULL, 10);
  ...
}
```

I see no line of input that this code does not fail/pass as OP might desire, except that I would allow `x` or `X`.

Comment: Note that the error-checking version would not fail on input of `"read 0x75088FF08"`.

Comment: @DavidBowling [foiled again](http://www.wantthistee.com/products/2/square/1120576.png)  See edit

Answer (score 2):

To parse both hexadecimal and decimal encoded numbers, use the`%i` conversion specifier.

The number of digits cannot be specified with the regular expression syntax you used in your format string, which explains why the second conversion fails.

Here is a simpler version:

```
 int n = sscanf(str, "read %i %i", &addr, &len);
```

Comment: Can the first %i really ensure that the value is parsed as hex? I understand if the number has A-F characters, but what if the number is "00000010"? Will this be read as 16 or 10?

Comment: @Martin-- The answer to your question is in the docs. `%i` expects input in the format of an [integer constant](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1). `00000010` will be interpreted as an octal number, 8 in decimal. If you want input to be interpreted as hex, use `0x00000010` or `0X00000010`.